# Debug with Xiaomi mi5 MIUI 8 Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot launch app from Android Studio. When i click "run", I select my device:

[image: I select the Xiaomi device]

And it appears an the following message:

[image: Uninstall app message]

But it is not true, the app is not installed in the device. In the "run" console, appears the following:

```
04/22 15:53:08: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\some.apk
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.package.app
Unknown failure (Failure - not installed for 0)
Error while Installing APK
```

I have activated USB debugging in the device.

Comment: Make sure that you have "Install via USB" checked as well in the MIUI 8 Developer Options, along with "USB Debugging" and "USB debugging (Security settings)".

Comment: Yes, I have checked it.

Comment: @aramburu Just restart your phone and try to run the project once again. I also faced the same problem in RedMi Note 3S.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Try TURN OFF "MIUI Optimization" from developer options**.
I've updated to **MIUI 8.2** and encountered same problem, found the solution here and it works. Good luck!

http://c.mi.com/thread-171377-1-0.html
[Off-Topic] [Device Team] Fix For Unable to Debug Android App From Android Studio

Comment: Not working in my case. My phone is Xiomi Y1, Android Version-7.1.2

Answer (score 1):

@Fisherman's answer haven't worked for me.

I needed also to uncheck `Verify apps over USB` and it worked like a charm.