# Instant run not working on Xiomi device

Tags: android, adb, android-instant-run

Instant run not working on Xiomi device.

When running full build and install(with all slices of APK) It is working. But when pushing a slice It is **rejected** from the phone, so uninstall Dialog comes.

> Adb command for pushing all slices

```
$ adb install-multiple -r -t D:\Project\WiSilica_Projects\Plt_main\L_and_B\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\directories.apk D:\Project\WiSilica_Projects\Plt_main\L_and_B\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
```

> Adb command for pushing single slice

```
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p com.lumens.andbeyond D:\Project\WiSilica_Projects\Plt_main\L_and_B\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\directories.apk 
Error while Installing APKs
```

> Image [image: Android studio image]

Comment: Look this answer, it was helpful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44091144/9424115

Comment: Not working in my case. My phone is Xiomi Y1, Android Version-7.1.2